# ¿como ocultar un label, boton u otro widget en una GUI? tkinter, python

Tags: python, tkinter, interfaz-gráfica

Quisiera saber si existe un metodo como el withdraw() para las ventanas pero para los widget para ocultar una label u otro widget dependiendo una condición

por ejemplo que diga bienvenindo / no bienvenido con una variable validación True/false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Natan, puedes usar **place_forget**, si es que usaste place para posicionar los componentes. Tambien existen grid_forget, y pack_forget, si es que los prefieres.
Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button

v = Tk()
v.geometry("240x40+500+200")
v.title("Prueba")

def borarOmostrar():
    if b.place_info() != {}:
        b.place_forget()
    else:
        b.place(x=170, y=5)

l = Button(v, text="Clic para mostrar u ocultar:", command=borarOmostrar)
b = Button(v, text="La victima")

l.place(x=5, y=5)
b.place(x=170, y=5)

v.mainloop()
```

Comment: Esto también funciona con label?
me da este error
img.place_forget()
AttributeError:'Nonetype' object has no attribute 'place forget''

para darte un poco de contexto lo meti en una fucion repeat que es llamada con el metodo after sera que por ser llamada dentro de otra clase no puede definir widget definido antes del mainloop?

Answer (score 0):

el problema basicamente era que estaba declarando el objeto asi

```
LabelUno= Label(raiz,text="Label").place(x=89,y=50)
```

y daba error cuando ejecutaba esto:

```
LabelUno.place_forget()
```

Entonces lo corregì haciendo esto:

```
LabelUno= Label(raiz,text="Label")
LabelUno.place(x=89,y=50)

LabelUno.place_forget()
```

Comment: El error que bien corregiste, se debe a que cuando declaras el posicionamiento de un widget como parte de la declaración de esta forma **boton = Button().place()**, el valor de boton es efectivamente un None, mientras que si haces **boton = Button()** y luego posicionas la variable **boton**, boton queda de tipo Button, por lo tanto, puedes manipular sus propiedades. Lo comento para que lo tengas presente en caso de que lo hayas resuelto por intuición, pero sin saber el motivo de este comportamiento.